# Re-name tag to use proper spacing

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I am trying to rename [outofcontrol](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outofcontrol) to [out-of-control](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/out-of-control) to use proper spacing by changing it on [the only post](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/208/kk2-1-6-falling-in-mid-air-and-losing-control) it is used on but I get this error:

> [image]

Can a mod (Catija) rename it please?

Comment: I was just coming here for the EXACT same reason.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 beat you to it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've justmerged [outofcontrol](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outofcontrol) into [out-of-control](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/out-of-control), and created a synonym for them too.

Comment: Thanks, offtopic but could you approve some of my tag wiki edits on the main site as there is no-one with this privilege? Thanks